# Android canvas:drawTextOnPath() behave differently on different devices

Tags: android

I have a requirement create circular menu with 8 items. For that i have created a custom view like below.

```
public class CircleTextView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {
private String BookName = null;
private int BookIndex;
private Context context;

public CircleTextView(Context context, String bookName, int bookIndex) {
    super(context);
    this.BookName = bookName;
    this.BookIndex = bookIndex;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(canvas == null)
        return;

    Path mArc = new Path();
    RectF ractangle;

    switch (this.BookIndex){
        case 0:
            ractangle = new RectF(70,70,270,270);
            //ractangle = new RectF(0,0,100,100);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 110, 230);
            break;
        case 1:
            ractangle = new RectF(-20,50,180,150);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 120, 290);
            break;
        case 2:
            ractangle = new RectF(-120,70,80,270);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 180, 270);
            break;
        case 3:
            ractangle = new RectF(50,-10,250,190);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 90, 180);
            break;
        case 4:
            ractangle = new RectF(0,0,0,0);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 5:
            ractangle = new RectF(-100,-10,100,190);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 310, 95);
            break;
        case 6:
            ractangle = new RectF(80,-110,280,90);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 60, 140);
            break;
        case 7:
            ractangle = new RectF(10,30,160,100);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 50, 100);
            break;
        case 8:
            ractangle = new RectF(-110,-80,90,80);
            mArc.addArc(ractangle, 0, 80);
            break;
    }
    Paint mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaintText.setTextSize(15f);
    mPaintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(getQualifiedName(this.BookName), mArc, 0, 0, mPaintText);

    this.setOnClickListener(this);
    invalidate();
}

private String getQualifiedName(String name){
    int length = name.length();
    String qName = name;
    if(length >8){
        qName = name.substring(0, 3) + ".." + name.substring((length - 5), length);
    }
    return qName.toUpperCase();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    CircleTextView _circleTextView = (CircleTextView)v;
    if (_circleTextView.getTag() != "") {
        ((PlayerActivity)context).loadChapters(_circleTextView.getTag().toString());
        TextView chapterTextView = (TextView)((PlayerActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.currentChapterTextView);
        chapterTextView.setText(((PlayerActivity) context).CurrentlyPlayingBook.getName());
        ((PlayerActivity)context).setAngleRange();
        ((PlayerActivity)context).setBackgroundImage(_circleTextView.getTag().toString());
        ((PlayerActivity)context).stopOngoingRequests();
    }
}
}
```

Above canvas drawing not behaves same in different devices. as clear from Screen 1 & Screen 2

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poCyv.jpg)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8zEN.png)

I am just struggling with resolving this.  Please help to resolve this.

Comment: well,  do not use hardcoded stuff like this `new RectF(-20,50,180,150);`

Comment: Thanks @Ark, But what else i can do. Can you please show me a direction

Answer (score 0):

Probably

1.You could use values relative to the width and height of View :

```
 int w=getWidth();
 int h=getHeight();
  .
  .
  .
  new RectF(w*x1, h*y1, w*x2, h*y2);
```

Where x1,y1 and x2,y2 can be used to fit the drawings properly.
OR

2. - Create a separate Canvas+Bitmap and then draw things on that
   - and then use Canvas.scale(float x,float y) to scale it to desired size
   - and then draw that bitmap for entirely separate drawings(the whole Text wrapped on Circle thing)  :

1.

```
 Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas tmp=new Canvas(bmp);
```

2
then draw your things on it :

```
 tmp.drawText....
 tmp.drawSomething...
```

3.
then scale it :

```
 tmp.save();
 tmp.scale(x,y);
 tmp.restore();
```

4.
lastly use that bitmap in your `onDraw` method:

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(tmp,0,0,null);
```

Hope you find it helpfull.